# Storing java util date into mysql as a timestamp

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using JPA and MySQl

In my domain object i have a date field as

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastSeenDate;
```

From my UI the date goes as a String in format dd-mm-yyyy

I used

```
final DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final Date date = format.parse(dateString);
```

but for String date

> 06-06-2013

the date stored in mysql is

> 0011-12-04 00:00:00.0

How do I store it into mysql to match the mysql format

Comment: use `format.format(date);`

Comment: please show what kind of date you get and what you want to get

Comment: What do you mean by "comes with timestamp"? I suspect you're mistaken about the meaning of a java.util.Date.

Comment: Your question is very vague. It's always best to show all of the relevant code, show the input, the actual output and the expected output...

Comment: what is exactly your dateString?

Answer (score 1):

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond
>   precision.

From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

The date class always has a time component.

Answer (score 0):

All dates in Java are essentially timestamps as they represent a single millisecond in time.

There's no way I can think of to deal only with dates but you might want to have a look at `java.util.Calendar`. If you can set the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds all to zero (or other defined time) you can then work with days, months and years more naturally. It's not a very good offering but it works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to JavaDocs: ***java.util.Date*** allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond.

So, it works like a database *Timestamp*. It would always have a time component although it may be all zeroes that is representing a midnight. But, you could use the same `SimpleDateFormat` to print out the `java.util.Date` without its time component.

```
final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
final Date utilDate = sdf.parse("2013-06-20");
System.out.println(sdf.format(utilDate)); // prints back 2013-06-20
```

Or, you may want to look into `java.sql.Date` which does not have a time component.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```